# Access running docker container filesystem

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am developing a WordPress theme and set up the development environment using docker. My docker-compose.yml volume property looks like this;

```
volumes:                                                                                                                
  - ~/WordPress/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

it mounts just the wp-content directory to the local machine. I now have to edit wp-config file which is in /var/www/html/ the docker image container. Can anyone here show me how to access and edit the wp-config file in the running docker container?

Comment: No, you need to change the configuration and recreate the container, at least.

Comment: That"s a relief. Any clue on accessing and editing the file?

Comment: Simply add another volume to your container

Comment: @mike I do not want add another volume because I just need to edit the file once or twice in the whole theme development process.

Comment: This is against best practices. Your app will stop working when you recreate your container

Answer (score 1):

You can run a shell terminal in the running container.

1. Get the container ID

   ```
    docker container ls
   ```
2. Run the terminal

   ```
    docker container exec -it container_ID "/bin/bash"
   ```

But, whatever change you do, it will not be persisted. You have to map this volume also.

```
 volumes:
      - ~/WordPress/wp-content:/var/www/html
```

Comment: How to make it persisted so that when I start the container tomorrow the changes still be in effect.

Comment: You need to add the volume like I said previously