# How to set up Wordpress to use mailhog without manual install of SMTP plugin for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, smtp

**Goal**

I've been been asked to help dockerize wordpress and mailhog so our devs can work locally. They want mailhog to capture any emails that wordpress would normally send out and just display them via the mailhog GUI.

I was able to set up a dockerized wordpress, mysql and an nginx server no problem.  Now I'm trying to integrate a mailhog server.

**What I've done so far:**

I've followed all the steps i found here:
https://gist.github.com/michaelbragg/13cde0a3b6ae4770bbd578a8db2b7918#file-msmtprc

The php.ini file gets copied over fine and I've verified the contents by logging into the container and doing this:

```
root@e4993627691a:/usr/bin# cat /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/msmtp -t"
mail.log = "/var/www/phpmail.log"
```

I also can see this config is being loaded by checking the phpinfo.php page:

[image]

It also looks like PHP has now been configured to use SMTP, per phpinfo.php:

[image]

[image]

mailhog server also is up and running.  I can launch the GUI app on localhost:8025 and i see that I have zero messages in my inbox
[image]

**What's Not Working**

I've been trying to force WordPress to create an email, and see if I end up with something in the mailhog inbox.  I used the forgot my password button on the wordpress log in screen and am requesting a password reset email.  But I see the following error on the screen:

[image]

**Questions**

Is there some other configuration that I need to apply to set up SMTP on the Wordpress server?  From what I've read, msmtp is an SMTP CLIENT, not an SMTP SERVER
I assumed Wordpress had an SMTP server baked in?  But when I check to see what ports are being used on the wordpress server, port 25 isn't one of them?

```
root@e4993627691a:/usr/bin# netstat -lp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:46515        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 [::]:9000               [::]:*                  LISTEN      1/php-fpm: master p 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:55171        0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
root@e4993627691a:/usr/bin#
```

I'm presenting browsing the various SMTP plugins available to wordpress to see if I install one of them, thing'll start working.  But if I don't have to install one, I'd prefer not too.

SOrry for the noob questions.  But I'm no wordpress dev, and not a system admin either.  Lol.  Any tips would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I got it working ... installed a plugin called WP Mail that disabled PHP mail() and set up SMTP. I used the wizard and chose custom SMTP server... and pointed it to my mailhog server, port 1025.

But I'm still wondering if there's another way to do this without installing this plugin?  If I can script everything in my docker files, that'd be great.

I also tried to edit my php.ini file that I'm copying over to see if i can just add the 2 settings:

```
SMTP="mailhog"
smtp_port="1025"
```

to see if that works.  And then I skipped the step of manually installing the plugin.  But that didn't work.

EDIT 3

```
// add Mailhog Action

add_action('wp_mail_failed', 'action_wp_mail_failed', 10, 1);

// configure PHPMailer to send through SMTP
add_action('phpmailer_init', function ($phpmailer) {

    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    // host details
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = false;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = '';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $phpmailer->Host = 'mailhog';
    $phpmailer->Port = '1025';
    // from details
    $phpmailer->From = 'webadmin@localhost';
    $phpmailer->FromName = 'Boss Hog';
    // login details
    $phpmailer->Username = null;
    $phpmailer->Password = null;

});
```

Comment: You obvs know your stuff from looking at your rating and profile. Check my answer on this question, this is how I docker-compose up/down my day-to-day wordpress local projects/repos on my mac, and using mailhog (which is awesome). This may help you or get you on the right track... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321295/using-volumes-in-docker-to-access-container-filesystem/65334037#65334037

Comment: @joshmoto my set up is basically like what you've done / described.  just wondering ... where is this functions.php located?  Do I edit the one for the selected theme?  wp_content/themes/myselectedtheme/functions.php? Ive tried that and then I try to use the forgot my password feature again but it doesn't work.  No errors.  but no emails.

Comment: yes you need to edit the running themes functions.php and place that php mailer code in there. Or you can create and mu-plugin containing this if you got a lot of sites to do.